# Surface Headphones as A2DP Sink and A2DP Source

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, headset

I have the Surface Headphones 2 (SH2) and use them with my Lenovo ThinkPad X1 (7th generation) running Ubuntu 20.04.

I can connect the (SH2) via Bluetooth. When connected I can choose between HSP/HFP and A2DP sink. If I choose A2DP sink the sound quality is significant better. Nevertheless if I choose A2DP sink for the outpu I can not use the Surface Headphones 2 as input device anymore.

Can I use the Surface Headphones 2 as A2DP sink and A2DP source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The A2DP protocol only supports communication in one direction according to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_(A2DP)).

**Thus a Bluetooth device (with one Bluetooth connection) can either be a A2DP source XOR be a A2DP sink.**